# not able to set owner Name in account.ownerId in apex class

Tags: apex, ownership

I am not able to set **Account.Owner = xyz** using apex class

can anybody help me out for this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure the OP is trying to set the ownerId in the Account prior to a DML operation.

However, as a side note, sometimes one is faced with modeling the relationship in Apex.

Hence, you can do the following:

```
Account a = new Account(owner = new User(firstname = 'foo', lastname = 'bar'));
```

You can't save the Account `a` unless you first null out `a.owner`. But there can be times where this coding trick can be useful, like in defaulting values on a VF page that shows multiple objects or in mocking arguments passed to methods under test.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `Account.OwnerId = someuserid`

Answer (score 2):

Account.Owner is not a correct field. It is a lookup field, it holds Id of a user. So, it should be `Account.OwnerId = 'ID '` as @Pepe said earlier.

Comment: Simply posting code to try is not a helpful answer, while the OP may have the issue resolved, they will not understand why the issue was and how you fixed it. So other can benefit from the work you put into the answer, please add a little information about what you found the issue to be and what it was you did to resolve the issue.

Comment: got it, updated my answer